# Custom Console Components not visible when "New Case" Button overridden

Tags: visualforce, button-overrides, custom-console-components, sidebar, custom-service-console

Custom Console Components are not showing (Knowledge / Lookbar Sidebars) are not visible when the NEW Case button is overriden by a VF Page which redirects users to Standard page or remain in VF Page itself. But the sidebars appear normally if the NEW button overriden is not there.

Comment: could you share the 2 screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

2015 Known Issues · No Fix: [Knowledge Sidebar is not displaying when the New Case Button is overwritten](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T1nnAAC)

*"...this is actually working as designed..."*